# International website (English and German) with GETTEXT and VIRTUAL subdirectories in the URL

Tags: apache, internationalization, gettext, multilingual, subdirectory

I have a website which uses two languages: English and German. For now, we use a cookie that stores the user's preferred language (en/de) and sets the language of `GETTEXT()` accordingly:

```
example.com/about-us.php
```

loads from our server page 'local-path-webspace/about-us.php' in English or German depending on the Cookie.

However, google cannot crawl our German page because their crawler does not set cookies.

What we want to achieve is that users now type an URL with a virtual subdirectory with the language they prefer:

```
example.com/en/about-us.php
```

for English and

```
example.com/de/about-us.php
```

for German.

Both pages above should load the same file on our server `local-path-webspace/about-us.php`, that is, folders `/en` and `/de` are VIRTUAL (should not exist in reality to avoid code redundance).

Inside file `about-us.php` we should be able to know which virtual folder was called (`/en` or `/de`) to be able to define the session variable that will define GETTEXT's language. Ideally using `$SERVER["REQUEST URI"]` or some global variable of PHP.

We tried to do it using `ALIAS_MOD in APACHE` to replace but without success. Is that the right way to go?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think using the RewriteEngine to transform /en resp. /de to GET parameters internally would be the better approach.

Comment: Thanks CBroe. The problem with that approach is that for some pages which already have parameters I have to have a different logic for the RewriteEngine (adding & at the end instead of ? in case no Get parameter exists). I got stuck at this point. Do you know a solution for that? Thanks!

Comment: You can just use the `[QSA]` flag to append the original query string to the new parameter you add during rewriting. The Rewrite engine will take care of handling ? and & correctly itself. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa